# How can I get an Esper windowed output and use it as input in another project?

Tags: output, esper

I already have a functional **Esper** code that prints in the screen like this:

```
    @Override
    public void update(EventBean[] newData, EventBean[] oldData) {
        System.out.println(newData[0].getUnderlying());
        }
```

`NewData[0].getUderlying()` already prints exactly how I need.

How can I get this `newData[0]`? I only could print `newData[0]` in the screen, but I couldn't be able to print this `newData[0]` (in the same format) in a text file or pass directly to my destination algorithm, which will have the output from **Esper** as its input.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use a FileWriter and write to the file? There is nothing different about the object that Esper provides then any other object in Java.

Comment: Thank you Paresh J. Worked.
Moreover do you know how can I get each time or length window individually? I wanna send each window as input in my other algorithm.